# Android : App crashes on Button click

Tags: android, button, android-intent, onclicklistener

I'm implementing a simple photo sharing client.

I have two buttons in my UI: one for browsing the image and the other for sending it.

The problem is that after browsing and selecting the image when I press the send button the app suddenly crashes.

Here's the code:

```
public class FileTransfer extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fs);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
        Button Browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBrowse);
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
        final TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

        Browse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

                    }
                });
        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Socket sock;
                try {
                    sock = new Socket("MY_PCs_IP", 1149); 
                    File myFile = new File (selectedImagePath); 
                    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);


  bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
                System.out.println("Sending...");
                os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                os.flush();
                sock.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            TextView path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
            path.setText("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing network operations on the UI thread. Don't do that. Google "NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: It's good to get into the habit of posting your logcat output when asking for help with a crash.

Comment: Please post the logcat details.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing long running task on UI(main) thread. Better consider using AsyncTask to perform the send action.